# QGIS Spatial Join returns NULL-values when using MultipolygonZ-geometry

Tags: qgis

I have a polygon geopackage and a pointfeature geopackage. Both have a size ~4GB and share the same CRS.
I want to join some attributes of the pointfeatures to the polygons, but each time I try to join them with the 'Join by location'-tool with the intersect-predicate and the join type 'Create separate feature for each matching feature (one-to-many)' in QGIS, the attributes are joined, but values of these attributes are always NULL.

What is happening here, and what is the solution?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the features intersect?

Comment: Yes, they should. When I do the same with a small subset, the join works.

Comment: Are you sure you are not looking for 'contains' instead of 'intersect'?

Comment: I'm sure, that I'm looking for intersect: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-difference-between-contains-and-intersects/226791
If a point sits right on the boundary of a polygon its attributes should also be joined to the polygon, not just when it is inside the boundaries.

Comment: Okay well then in that case, I'm afraid I can't do any more problem solving without a subset of your data...Can you provide a subset where you know there should be some intersect results? Maybe put it on google drive or whatever else you use?

Comment: I just found out, the polygons are of class 'MultipolygonZ' and when I apply Multipart-to-Singlepart on the polygons, they become 'Polygons (PolygonZ)', and THEN the join works on it. However, after applying multipart-to-singlepart', each polygon duplicates (I think some have even more than one duplicate). So I guess, I'm facing here a problem based on the class MultipolygonZ. I dont't know anything yet about this feature class. Do you?

Comment: @Walshe_d Thank you for trying to help. Unfortunately the data is sensitve, and I'm not allowed to share any of it.

Comment: Please, run the _Check Validity_ tool with the multipolygons layer as input and share a screenshot of the attributes table of the _ERROR_ output layer.